# spring batch passing a dynamic file name as JobParameter

Tags: shell, spring-batch

Hello Iwant to develop a spring batch project with (ksh) shell script;
The shell script scan a folder and send the input file name to spring batch (send request).
If spring batch retuen failed then shell script send mail to the admin system.

the Shell script code:

[image]

graph

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hello; how do spring batch receive the file name and process it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do spring batch receive the file name and process it?

If you use Spring Boot to create a runnable jar of your job (which seems to be your case), you can pass job parameters as key/value pairs. Here is an example with a `filename` parameter:

```
java -jar myjob.jar filename=/path/to/file
```

Looking at your shell script, it could be something like:

```
java -jar testmultiple.jar filename=$i
```

If you don't use Spring Boot (this does not look to be your case, but I mention it here for reference), you can also pass job parameters as key/value pairs to the `CommandLineJobRunner` class:

```
java org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner myJobContext.xml myJob filename=/path/to/file
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud, I find a model of spring batch spring boot with api REST luncher and input file name (arguments) without xml, thanks.

Comment: As I said, I added the example with `CommandLineJobRunner` as a reference. With spring boot and java config, the first example should work in your case.

Comment: Good morning Mahmoud, how can i expose a function so that shell script send me the file name and after if the step forwarding null i force the job to stop and i return to the shell script a return code eg "10" to tell it 1: it's step 1 and 0: it's failed, thank you very much mahmoud

Comment: hello, okay, I have to project shell script and spring batch, I want to:
1. the shell script scan a folder and for each file launches the jar with inputfile name arguments;
2. The spring batch does step processing, if the step returns null we stop the job and return a code "10" for the shell to send a mail for the manager else the job continue to next step.
My question: how can I create a function to lauch the job, get step status and return result to shell.
Thank you Mahmoud :)